# Swift - Offscreen Rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, core-graphics

I encountered as issue while debugging an app performance written in Swift. 
It is important note about Swift because the app uses code rewritten from Obj-C. I mean same methods and functions but in a different language.

I launched the app on the 9.3 simulator, turned on offscreen rendered coloring and everything were lightening with yellow.

[image]

But I know every element is optimised and it shouldn't look like that. Here how the same screen looks for Obj-C version. Only the status bar is highlighted and corners of the text input field below the table.

[image]

How could I deal with that? Is it my bad or a Swift bug in charge?

**Edit**: The issue is reproduced even for an empty table. Look for the Swift project and move on to ChatViewController. It contains only a tableView inherited from SLKTextViewController.

**Edit2**: The issue also could be reproduced on an empty project with just a navigation controller and its root view controller.

[image]

PS:
A source code could be found here for a Swift version: https://github.com/Kilograpp/Mattermost-iOS-Swift

An Obj-C version:
https://github.com/Kilograpp/Mattermost-iOS

Comment: Could you please create a minimum reproducible example? Really we cannot compare two entire projects.

Comment: Okay, would provide soon

Comment: @Sulthan, I made an edit to the post. An issue could be reproduced with an empty SLKTextViewController

Comment: Even an empty view controller reproduces the issue. But a fresh project acts fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally figured out what was it all about. 
When a root navigation controller has a translucent navigation bar it causes the issue.